# Python: Assign Labels to values in an array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have an array which represents some time series data:

```
array([[[-0.59776013],
    [-0.59776013],
    [-0.59776013],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [ 0.31863936],
    [ 0.31863936],
    [ 0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [ 0.59776013],
    [ 0.59776013],
    [ 0.59776013],
    [ 0.93458929],
    [ 0.93458929],
    [ 0.93458929],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.06270678],
    [-0.06270678],
    [-0.06270678],
    [-0.06270678],
    [-0.06270678],
    [-0.06270678],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [ 0.75541503],
    [ 0.75541503],
    [ 0.75541503],
    [ 0.93458929],
    [ 0.93458929],
    [ 0.93458929],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [ 0.75541503],
    [ 0.75541503],
    [ 0.75541503],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [-0.31863936],
    [ 0.31863936],
    [ 0.31863936],
    [ 0.31863936],
    [ 0.        ],
    [ 0.        ],
    [ 0.        ],
    [ 0.        ],
    [ 0.        ],
    [ 0.        ],
    [ 0.        ],
    [ 0.        ]]])
```

The unique values in this array are:

```
np.unique(sax_dataset_inv)
array([-0.59776013, -0.31863936, -0.06270678,  0.        ,  0.31863936,
    0.59776013,  0.75541503,  0.93458929])
```

**My task**

Assign either 'F' for fast, 'S' for slow or 'M' for medium to a given array value.

**My attempt**

I can do it for 2 assignments, 'F' or 'S':

```
sax_list = ['F' if element < 0 else 'S' for element in list(sax_dataset_inv.flatten())]
```

However I cannot understand how I can do the same expression above for 3 different labels.

**Desired Output**

Take an example array of [-3-2-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

The values -3 to -1 inclusive should be assigned 'F'.
Values 0 to 3 inclusive should be assigned 'M'.
Values greater than 3 should be assigned 'S'.

Comment: Helpful: [ternary operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: also what to do with values greater than -1 and smaller than 0 ?

Comment: Have you considered initializing your resulting array with 'M' and then checking if the entry is bigger/smaller than your bounds?

Comment: My attempt has been highlighted above. I edited the question to show that I can do the task for two labels. If element<0 assign 'F', else assign 'S'. Does If element<0 assign 'F', if element in range(0,0.4)assign 'M', else assign 'M' make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** OP's intervals are `[-3,-1], [0,3] & (3,..)`, so I am only assuming *integral* values. The conditions can be altered accordingly, but the design remains.

Using `list comprehensions` for `if-elif-else`:

```
my_list = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

my_list_mapping = ['F' if ((i >= -3) & (i <= -1)) else 'M' if ((i >= 0) & (i <= 3)) else 'S' for i in my_list]
print(my_list_mapping)
    ['F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'S', 'S', 'S']
```

Comment: if value is `-0.5` the array element will be `'S'`, right ?

Comment: Well, I assumed that OP is concerned with only integral values, because he specified the intervals as such.

Comment: no hard feelings, it's the OPs description of the problem that's flawed

Comment: His intervals are `[-3,-1], [0,3], (3,..)`

Comment: This is what I was looking for. My if-elif-else condition was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Murray Pleasure. You have redeemed me ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
arr = np.array([-3-2-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
new_arr = np.zeros(shape = arr.shape, dtype=np.str)

new_arr[(arr>3)] = 'S'
new_arr[((arr>=-3) & (arr<=-1))] = 'F'
new_arr[((arr>=0)&(arr<=3))] = 'M'
new_arr
array(['', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'S', 'S', 'S'], dtype='<U1')
```

The values that don't match your condition will remain empty strings.

Also you can use [numpy.empty](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy.empty) to initialize an empty array:

```
new_arr = np.empty(shape = arr.shape, dtype=np.str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for vectorized solution:

```
new_arr = np.select([arr>3, (arr>=-3) & (arr<=-1), (arr>=0)&(arr<=3)],
                    ['S','F','M'], 
                    default='')
print (new_arr)

['F' 'F' 'F' 'M' 'M' 'M' 'M' 'S' 'S' 'S']
```

**Performance**:

```
arr = np.array([-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6] * 1000)

my_list = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6] * 1000

In [276]: %timeit my_list_mapping = ['F' if ((i >= -3) & (i <= -1)) else 'M' if ((i >= 0) & (i <= 3)) else 'S' for i in my_list]
1.14 ms ± 67.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [277]: %timeit np.select([arr>3, (arr>=-3) & (arr<=-1), (arr>=0)&(arr<=3)],['S','F','M'],  default='')
172 µs ± 7.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can neatly achieve your result by using the `map` function from the Python core library
Let's say your mapping function would look something like this:

```
def mapping_function(value):
    if value >= -3 and value <= -1:
        return 'F'
    elif value >= 0 and value <= 3:
        return 'M'
    elif value > 3:
        return 'S'
    else:
        return 'U'  # eg. as undefined
my_array = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
mapped_vals = map(mapping_function, my_array)
# if you want a list
my_mapped_list = list(mapped_vals)
```

I think it is a readable and clear solution.

Since you have tagged it as a pandas question, take a look at [pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) function from their docs.
Instead of using it as map, you pass the mapping function as an argument to the `apply` function.